# Не могу подключится к своему ftp-серверу, не могу понять какой для него IP адрес использовать

Tags: ftp-сервер

Я хочу сделать FTP-сервер на FileZilla и заходить на него с компьютера в учебном заведении. Я поставил в пассивный мод свой IP, который взял с сайт 2ip.ru, но зайти, например, со своего компьютера по этому IP я не могу. FarManager меня не пускает и пишет, что в доступе отказано. Помогите!
Изменение: Вот, что я получил, но файлы на сервере так и не отобразились
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Изменение: Зашел через Total Comannder, он не стал сопротивлялся и пустил меня, заходил я со своего компьютера.
Изменение: FileZilla Client пишет, что  соединение отклонено сервером :\

Comment: а сам ftp находится дома? скорее всего у Вас nat (типичная ситуация) и так просто не зайти. Берите реальный айпи и тогда будет работать

Comment: А где его можно взять?

Comment: у своего провайдера. Но обычно оно стоит каких то небольших денег. в районе 1 евро в месяц.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения своего ip поищите в гугле сайты вроде 2ip.ru или прочих.
P.S. Комментировать не могу так что как то так)

Comment: Так я его нашел, но все равно не работает.

Comment: Жаль, возможно проблема всё же не в IP. Пробовали 0.0.0.0 или 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Так то у меня работает, но мне нужно из другого места получать доступ к серверу.

Comment: Может проблема у другого ПК? Пробовали через третье устройство подключиться?

Comment: Пробовал, но ничего не получилось

Comment: А может быть такое, что со своего IP адреса я захожу на сервер, у которого такой же IP (т.е. мой сервер), и поэтому не пускает?

Comment: если у двух компютеров одинаковые айпи, то либо они за натом и у них локальные адреса (что то вида 192.168.*.*) либо админы получат по шапке.

Comment: А из-за этого могут быть какие-нибудь недоразумения в виде отказа доступа сервером?

Comment: Короче, я просто создал сеть VPN, к которой подключаюсь с удаленного компьютера, для ftp-сервера я указал ip моей сети VPN. И теперь, просто подключаясь к этой сети, я могу зайти на свой ftp-сервер. Как-то так.

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно пробросить порт через ваш роутер. FTP слушает 21 порт. На вашем роутере есть функция NAT, там создаёте правило, что все что приходит из вне на порт 21 должно транслироваться на IP адрес вашего ПК и порт 21. Не забудьте о настройках Firewall windows (нужно разрешить доступ по 21 порту)

Comment: Хорошо, попробую.

Comment: это если на роутере реальный айпи. а если провайдер экономит и уже за нат бросил пользователей, то тут все чуточку сложнее

Comment: Тогда нужно использовать сервис типа Dyndns и подключаться к FTP по имени хоста.

Comment: если у  автора провайдерский днс, то dyndns не поможет

Comment: Автор может выбрать любой ДНС, собственно никто не мешает этого зделать установив свои ДНС в настройках роутера (типа 1.1.1.1 или 8.8.8.8), а dyndns это сервис предоставляющий доступ к вашему роутеру, который за NAT, по имени хоста в интернете.

Comment: Сделал, как вы написали вчера, теперь при подключении к FTP серверу по моему IP мне не отказывают в доступе, а просто идет долгая загрузка, после ничего нет.

Comment: Вот тут хорошо всё описано - https://sonikelf.ru/sozdaem-svoj-sobstvennyj-ftp-server-na-baze-filezilla-server/